# Why is the html() function from jQuery creating an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've found out this weird "glitch", that if I try to put HTML in an element, it just starts infinite looping.

Here is the code that works **correct**

```
$.each(JSEFileNames, function(key, value){
  $.ajax({
     url: "/" + key,
     cache: false,
   }).done(function (r) {
     alert(r);
   });
 });
```

And here is the code that creates an infinite loop:

```
$.each(JSEFileNames, function(key, value){
  $.ajax({
    url: "/" + key,
    cache: false,
  }).done(function (r) {
   $("#searchBox").html(r); // here it starts to loop.
  });
});
```

And here is my full code:
https://jsbin.com/hesaxezure/edit?html,js,output

What produces this weird behavior? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What you mean of infinite loop?

Comment: There's nothing in the code you've shown which would create an infinite loop. What event are you running the code under?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan This is my full code: https://jsbin.com/hesaxezure/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @GerritLuimstra About your code: please learn what Arrays are, and how to use them. All these comma-separated strings are horrible.

Comment: @Thomas This is a simple setup and therefor I chose to pick something simple.

Comment: but that's exactly the point, your code (on jsbin) ain't simple, it's primitive, you are basically parsing and serializing all over the place. I'll put later an example together how it could look like (from what I understand that you want to achieve)

Comment: I have fixed it. The problem was, that I was inserting the code (that was on the index.php) inside an element. This caused the code to be ran twice and so there was a "code"-ception